# Is O(log n) the correct running time T(n) for this?

Tags: c, time

Here it is:

```
for(i=n;i >0; i=i/2)
    printf(“%i”,i);
```

I'm still new to this and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  `i` is halved on each iteration until it reaches 0, so the iteration count is log(n).  If n is initially <= 0, it will terminate immediately.

Comment: Wrong. `“%i”` is non-standard and will produce compile error in normal compiler, so there are no running time for this.

Comment: To clarify, @MikeCAT is complaining about the incorrect quote characters used in the post, i.e. `“%i”`.  It should be `"%i"`.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in comments. You're right about complexity of this piece of code. Just use `"` rather than smart quote `”`. As pointed by @John Bollinger `”` is not a part of standard C basic source character set.

Regarding checking complexity, You can verify it yourself with basic log usage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double getLog2(double n) {  
    return log(n) / log(2);  
} 

int main() {
    int n = 32;
    int nIterations = 0;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        nIterations++;
    }

    printf("nIterations = %d, getLog2(%d) = %d", nIterations, n, getLog2(n));
}
```

When you'll run this, you would be able to see `nIterations` equal to log to the base 2 of N. Here is a sample run with `N=64`:

```
src : $ gcc logncomplexity.c -lm
src : $ ./a.out 
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
nIterations = 7, getLog2(64) = 7
```

Comment: `%i` is entirely as standard as `%d`, and the two have identical meaning as `printf` field directives.  There is no particular reason for the OP to change.  But they *do* need to use ASCII double-quote characters (`"`), as opposed to the "smart" quotes that they present in the question.  The latter are not in C's basic source character set, and a compiler that accepts them at all is unlikely to recognize them as delimiters for string literals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I couldn't notice it's not a `"`. I'll update my answer